# how to add median value to rows?

Tags: r, median

I have a data frame (data) with 53 columns (ID column plus 52 numeric values).  I can add a column with mean with the following:

```
data$mean <- rowMeans(data[,2:51],na.rm = TRUE) # add mean of rows
```

But, I cannot do the same for median with the following:

```
data$medians <- rowMedians(month.sum[,2:51],na.rm = TRUE) # add medians of rows
```

I installed the package **matrixStats** which includes `rowMedians`, but it does not work for me.

Comment: are you sure you want to use `data` for the means and `month.sum` for the medians?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: I think @rawr is on to something (do they have a different number of rows?) but it's impossible to tell when the only information you provide is "it does not work for me".

Answer (score 5):

You can apply arbitrary functions to rows with `apply`. Use

```
apply(data[,2:51],1, median, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Read the `?apply` help page for more information.