# R How to take Median of Rows in Dataframe

Tags: r, median

I am wondering if there is any way to a median of the rows in a data frame. I understand the function rowmeans exists, but I do not believe there is a row median function. I would like to store the results in a new column in the dataframe. Here is my example

I tried to look online. There was one mention of row medians, but I could not find the function in R.

```
 C1<-c(3,2,4,4,5)
   C2<-c(3,7,3,4,5)
   C3<-c(5,4,3,6,3)
   DF <- data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"),C1=C1,C2=C2,C3=C3)

   DF 


  # This is as far as I have gotten, but not streamlined

  MA <- median(C(3, 3, 5). na.rm = T)   # A
  MB <- median(C(2, 7, 4). na.rm = T)   # B
  MC <- median(C(4, 3, 3). na.rm = T)   # C
  MD <- median(C(4, 4, 6). na.rm = T)   # 4
  ME <- median(C(5, 5, 3). na.rm = T)   # E

  CM <- c(MA, MB, MC, MD, ME)C1<-c(3,2,4,4,5)


   ID C1 C2 C3
  1  A  3  3  5
  2  B  2  7  4
  3  C  4  3  3
  4  D  4  4  6
  5  E  5  5  3

   ID C1 C2 C3  CM
  1  A  3  3  5
  2  B  2  7  4
  3  C  4  3  3
  4  D  4  4  6
  5  E  5  5  3
```

Is there anyway I can streamline the process so it would be like DF$CM <- median(...

Comment: There's function `matrixStats::rowMedians`. [Related: how to add median value to rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077887/how-to-add-median-value-to-rows); [How to calculate row medians efficiently with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885416/how-to-calculate-row-medians-efficiently-with-data-table)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find median of every row using matrixStats::rowMedians](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525152/find-median-of-every-row-using-matrixstatsrowmedians)

Comment: As noted by jogo, your go to function for anything rowwise should be `apply` with the dimension set to 1.

Answer (score 17):

To calculate the median of `df`, you can do the following

```
df$median = apply(df, 1, median, na.rm=T)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to use `dplyr`, you can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902842/min-and-median-of-multiple-columns-of-a-df-by-row-in-r), especially [mpalanco's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2963704/mpalanco) answer. Briefly, after using `rowwise` to indicate that the operation should be applied by row (rather than to the entire data frame, as by default), you can use `mutate` to calculate and name a new column off of a selection of existing columns. Check out the documentation on each of those functions for more details.

E.g.,

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(CM = median(c(C1, C2, C3), na.rm = TRUE))
```

will yield the output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  ID       C1    C2    C3    CM
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         3     3     5     3
2 B         2     7     4     4
3 C         4     3     3     3
4 D         4     4     6     4
5 E         5     5     3     5
```

Comment: row-wise is painfully slow with large datasets

Answer (score 6):

Just a little bit more flexible and up to date. We use `c_across` with `rowwise` function and it allows to use `tidy-select` semantics. Here we choose `where` to specify we only want the numeric column to calculate the median.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(med = median(c_across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Rowwise: 
  ID       C1    C2    C3   med
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         3     3     5     3
2 B         2     7     4     4
3 C         4     3     3     3
4 D         4     4     6     4
5 E         5     5     3     5
```

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner that allows you to pick your desired columns:

```
apply(DF[, c("C1", "C2", "C3")], 1, median)

  ID C1 C2 C3 CM
1  A  3  3  5  3
2  B  2  7  4  4
3  C  4  3  3  3
4  D  4  4  6  4
5  E  5  5  3  5
```